# How to fix damage to my fence door's latch?

Tags: doors, fence

I have a wooden fence door with a metal latch. As shown in the below picture, something happened recently that caused the metal latch piece (and some of the attached wood) to separate from the fence door.

I want to fix this because the separation makes latching the door difficult. What is the best way to repair this? Might applying wood glue, along with using a large clamp or vice to push the separating wood back into position, repair this?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would,

- unscrew the latch and remove it,
- apply wood glue under the broken piece,
- clamp it and let it dry for an hour or two
- drill some deep pilot holes through 95% of the thickness of the whole gate
- reattach the latch with **longer screws** .

I would consider using bolts instead, with washers to spread the load on the far side.

Comment: Might also move the whole latch up or down an inch when re-installing it (both parts.)

Comment: I would skip directly to step 5: longer screws. Glue has no place here. If longer screws don't do it, move on to bolts.